# Apache not able to redirect to root folder in remote server

Tags: php, apache, apache2

I configured apache and php on remote server and apache works.
When I place my php file in /var/www The URL is not redirecting.

When I type the url http://xxx.xx.xx.x
I get below output:

```
It works!
This is the default web page for this server.

The web server software is running but no content has been added, yet.
```

In /etc/apache2/apache.conf I don't find below block
I add below block and restarted apache still it's doesn't redirect to /var/www

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName xxx.xx.xx.x
DocumentRoot /var/www/
</VirtualHost>
```

Please do let me know.

Comment: Have you added a <Directory> directive for /var/www to let apache know you will allow access to that directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are not using *exactly* the same the server name from the ServerName field to access the server. As such the request is being serviced by the default virtual host - which Apache documentation states is the first VirtualHost directive found in the configuration file.

Remove the first VirtualHost directive and apache will default to using your virtual host settings.